# Does CoreBluetooth implement Direct Test Mode?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I learned that the Bluetooth 4.0 specification states a Direct Test Mode for the RF PHY (Bluetooth Core Specification v4.1, Volume 6, Part F). I'm using a BLE112 module, and Bluegiga's API implements these testing commands as test_phy_end(), test_phy_rx() and test_phy_tx().
Does CoreBluetooth implement them somehow? If not, is there another way to access the Direct Test Mode in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently no there is not.
I spoke with a colleague who develops BLE firmwares.
You have to connect physically to the BLE chip.

A way to do it, could be for example, to have a MFI device that you connect to the lightning/30-pin connectors, and connect it to the BLE chip. But I don't know if it exists, and you may have to do it yourself.